# Relationship between nuclear spin and nuclear magnetic moment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

We know that nuclear magnetic moment can be expressed in terms of the expected value for nuclear spin as:

$$\langle\mu\rangle =[g_lj+(g_s-g_l)\langle s_z\rangle]\frac{\mu_N}{\hbar}$$

(Cf. Krane), where $\vec{j}$ is the *total* angular momentum, $\vec{l}+\vec{s}$.

How does the expected $\langle s_z\rangle$ value relate to the $\vec{j}$-component of spin, $\langle s_j\rangle$? Krane mentions that only that value is needed, given that it remains constant.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give more more details about your source (so far define just as "Krane"). I'm puzzled by "$\vec{j}$-component of spin $\langle s_j \rangle$" -- what do you mean?

Comment: The source is Kenneth Krane's book 'Introductory Nuclear Physics'. $\langle s_j \rangle$ is the expected value for the $\vec{j}$-component of the spin vector, $\vec{s}$. 

We assume a fixed $z$ axis around which $\vec{j}$ -the sum of angular and spin momentum- rotates. In the book, it is said that if we want to measure $\langle s_z \rangle$, it suffices to know $\langle s_j \rangle$. Why?

Comment: I have not access to the book now, but I remember that In Krane's book the terminology is a bit sloppy. He calls spin to total angular momentum, can this be the source of your doubt?

Comment: I don't think so, total angular momentum is clearly defined as the sum of angular momentum and spin.

Comment: OK, I found the book. It seems that he´s applying the **Wigner-Eckart theorem** although it does not say it explicitly. Also, if I remember correctly there was an error in one of the formulas 5.9 although I do not remember in which one. I will try to elaborate later...

Comment: @Slaviks: What he calls "$j$-component of spin $\langle \hat{s}_j\rangle$" is the projection of the spin vector $\mathbf{s}$ in the direction of the total angular momentum $e_\mathbf{j}=\mathbf{j}/|\mathbf{j}|$.

Answer (score 5):

From the magnetic moment
$$\mathbf{\mu}=\mathbf{\mu_L}+ \mathbf{\mu_S}=(g_l \mathbf{L}+g_s\mathbf{S})\frac{\mu_N}{\hbar}\tag1$$
take the scalar product with $\bf{J}$
$$\mathbf{\mu_J} ·\mathbf{J}=(1/2(g_l +g_s)\mathbf J^2+1/2(g_l -g_s)(\mathbf L^2-\mathbf S^2))\frac{\mu_N}{\hbar} \tag2$$
so with commutator relation $$\mu=(1/2(g_l +g_s)j+1/2(g_l -g_s)\frac{(l-s)(l+s+1)}{j+1}) \mu_N \tag3$$

since $s=1/2$ and $j= l\pm1/2$ you end with two possible values for $\mu$
$$\mu=(jg_l-1/2(g_l -g_s)) \mu_N \quad\text{for }j= l+1/2\\
\mu=(jg_l+(g_l -g_s)\frac{j}{2j+1}) \mu_N \quad\text{for }j= l-1/2 \tag4$$

this is your $⟨s⟩$ projection in the $j$ direction.

For $s\neq 1/2$ equation, $(3)$ still holds. But for $s>l$ the factor must be changed to the general form $$\frac{l(l+1)- s (s+1)}{j+1}.$$

Comment: Nuclei usually have more than one nucleon in them, so you cannot assume s=1/2. The spin operator **S** in question is presumably S_1 + S_2 + ..., i.e. the sum of the spin operators for each nucleon.

Comment: Edited answer. I was thinking on an odd unpaired nucleus. However without proper quantum chromodynamics all classical answers are approximations. I am not a specialist on particle physics.

Comment: What is the relation between $\mu_\mathbf{J}$ and $\mu$ in equation (2) and (3)? It seems that you have divided both sides by $(j+1)$ to get (3) from (2). Could you explain why?

Comment: *so with commutator relation* -- Which commutator relation are you referring to?